# Can I create a subdomain site on the same server as my top level

Tags: dns, webserver, subdomain

I have tried to figure this out, but the only thing I can come up with is I need a separate server.

I want to create a mobile site for my existing site. I use zoneedit.com which allowed me to create mydomain.com and m.mydomain.com. My UI is completely (with a few exceptions) driven by css. I want to use the functionality from my top level with a different css file for my mobile subdomain site. But, the only way I see it working is if I created a new server for the mobile site. The only reason I say this is because if I redirect the user who is on a mobile device to m.mydomain.com and simply change the css then it is pointless for me to have a m.mydomain.com address. Right?

My question is basically can I have a different css file depending on the domain not the browser?

I really hope that makes sense!

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: The `m.example.com` vs `www.example.com` is really nice because most mobile browser users I know really like being able to get the full desktop version on their mobile device. Changing `m` to `www` or `www` to `m` allows users to pick which one they want very easily, so I think it is still very much worth supporting both. Hosting both on a single machine with a single server is easy, but requires knowing more details. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do this on the same server:

- One strategy is URL rewrites based on hostname.
- Another is to have the same webroot for the server but point the location for the css directory to another on-disk location
- A third is to serve the stylesheet with a scripting language that inspects the HTTP host header.

In response to the comment by OP:
The simplest solution is:

```
// Given that $browserIsMobile is a boolean set by the script
if( $browserIsMobile && $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'm.example.com' )
    send_mobile_stylesheet();
else
    send_desktop_stylesheet();
```

Comment: I am doing research on these responses right now. One thing I forgot to mention was that I am using php and ajax. The style sheets are echoed from php. So, I can change them according to the browser (figuring out the browser is a different issue I'm assuming). I think Mel suggests that in his third solution if I understand correctly.